# How can I ignore special characters in CodeIgniter URL Segment for query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've tried this a number of ways but I have a client being rather particular on this subject and I am not sure how to make this happen exactly as he wants.

We have a controller called Articles.

To find an article we are using the path /articles/year/month/date/article-title-as-is-in-database-but-highphenated

The controller takes only that last portion of the data, replaces hyphens with spaces, and looks in the articles table for article_title that matches the string.

Now he has some articles with colons and certain other special chars in them.

SO my question is, if we have "This: is my article name" in the database, his preferred link would be "/this-is-my-article-name/".. well, the query returns no results because we've replaced the colon with nothing.. how do we fetch the resulting article?!

I tried something akin to:

```
$this->db->select('(SELECT * FROM articles WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(articles.article_title, "-", ""), ":", ""),"!", "") LIKE "%'.$string.'%")', FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row_array();
```

However that did not work- it simply resulted in this:

> Error Number: 1241
>
> Operand should contain 1 column(s)
>
> SELECT (SELECT * FROM articles WHERE
>   REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(articles.article_title, "-", ""), ":", ""),
>   "!", "") LIKE "%Computer Build of the Month : April 2015%")
>
> Filename: C:\mstsage\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 331

Thank you to whatever genius helps me resolve this!

Comment: Why not add a separate field to your database with the url friendly segment?

Comment: A little bit off-topic, but I recommend adding the post ID to the URL, in the odd case when two articles might share the same name

Answer (score 2):

This error was resulted because you are using the wrong method to execute your query. In order to run a queries you use the function `$this->db->query`, see [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#regular-queries) for more info.

In order to fix the error you got change your code to:

```
$sql = '(SELECT * FROM articles WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(articles.article_title, "-", ""), ":", ""),"!", "") LIKE "%'.$string.'%")';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->row_array();
```

Extra: Codeigniter has a [query builder class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-builder-class) to facilitate queries.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up resolving the other a completely different way, but I'm glad to see what the error was in what I was doing. Rather than this, ultimately I opted to add another column called article_uri, in which I took the title string, swapped spaces with dashes, removed all other special chars, and just used that column to look up from the URI segment later on. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If your article name is stored in db as "This: is my article name" and if you use the path as /articles/year/month/date/this--is-my-article-name. So your controller converts the highphenated article name to "this  is my article name". Now your are in a point you compare "this  is my article name" got from the controller and  "This: is my article name" in the db.

Unfortunately mysql doesnot offer any regular expression replace function, you can create a custom one like the below

https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-remove-special-characters-by-mysql-custom-functionexample.html

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `removeSpacialChar` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`degree`@`%` FUNCTION `removeSpacialChar`(`in_str` varchar(4096)) RETURNS varchar(4096) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

      DECLARE out_str VARCHAR(4096) DEFAULT ''; 

      DECLARE c VARCHAR(4096) DEFAULT ''; 

      DECLARE pointer INT DEFAULT 1; 



      IF ISNULL(in_str) THEN

            RETURN NULL; 

      ELSE

            WHILE pointer <= LENGTH(in_str) DO 



                  SET c = MID(in_str, pointer, 1); 



                  IF (ASCII(c) >= 48 AND ASCII(c) <= 57) OR (ASCII(c) >= 65 AND ASCII(c) <= 90) OR (ASCII(c) >= 97 AND ASCII(c) <= 122) THEN

                      SET out_str = CONCAT(out_str, c); 

                  ELSE

                      SET out_str = CONCAT(out_str, ' ');   

                  END IF; 



                  SET pointer = pointer + 1; 

            END WHILE; 

      END IF; 



      RETURN out_str;

END $$

DELIMITER ;





SELECT * FROM articles WHERE removeSpacialChar(articles.article_title)="this is my article name";
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the error message reported by MySQL server. It contains the SQL keyword `SELECT` followed by your entire query.

This happens because the `$this->db` object is a connection to the database but also a query builder. It's [`select()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data) method requires as arguments only the expressions to put in the `SELECT` clause of the query it builds. Use its [`where()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data) method to specify the `WHERE` conditions and so on.

If you want to write your own SQL query (and not use the query builder) then you can use the [`query()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html) method. It just sends the query to the server, without changing it:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(articles.article_title, "-", ""), ":", ""),"!", "") LIKE "%'.$string.'%")', FALSE);
```

Read the documentation page ["Generating Query Results"](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) to learn how to use the object returned by `$this->db->query()`.